# Create a sequence using fixed interval

Tags: excel-formula, sequence, intervals

I need help for creating the sequence with specific increment for specific interval.

[image]

I would like to create a series as shown in red from the data as shown in green. The series shall get updated automatically as per the data in green.

Comment: That doesn't seem too complex. What did you try so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Show us your code and inform us about where things go wrong.

Comment: I would like to do it in excel

Comment: Actually I don't do coding, I wanted to do it just with formulas in excel but its not working.... If you can help me...

Comment: Well, we won't write your formulas for you. So show us what you have done so far and we may help you solve your own problems.

Answer (score 0):

Step one would be to create your series.  Set your first cell to the start of the series (CellG2 =A2).  For the cells after that use VLOOKUP to select the spacing between numbers.

```
CellG3 =G2 + VLOOKUP( $G2, $A$2:$D$5, 3, TRUE)
```

Step two, look up your quantity via similar method.

```
CellH2 =VLOOKUP( $G2, $A$2:$D$5, 4, TRUE)
```

Step 3 is optional but you could add some error checking so you wouldn't have to manually update the length of the columns.

This assumes your series are in order and have no gaps between them.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes sample data and series data are located at `A1:D5` and `F1:H50`. Series data includes the working field `Row` *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*

**Row**: Working field to calculate the corresponding row for each series. Enter this formula in cell `F2` then copy till last record

```
=IF( EXACT( $F1, F$1 ), 2,
IF( OR( $F1 > ROWS( $A$1:$A$5 ), EXACT( $F1, CHAR(133) ) ), CHAR(133),
SUM( $F1, ( SUM( $G1, INDEX( $C$1:$C$5, $F1 ) ) > INDEX( $B$1:$B$5, $F1 ) ) * 1 ) ) )
```

**Series** : Enter this formula in `G2` then copy till last record

```
=IF( EXACT( $G1, $G$1 ), INDEX( $A$1:$A$5, $F2 ),
IF( EXACT( $F2, CHAR(133) ), "",
IF( $F2 > ROWS( $A$1:$A$5 ), INDEX( $B$1:$B$5, $F1 ),
SUM( $G1, INDEX( $C$1:$C$5, $F2 ) ) ) ) )
```

**Quantity** : Enter this formula in `H2` then copy till last record

```
=IF( EXACT($F2 , CHAR(133) ) , "" ,
INDEX( $D$1:$D$5 ,
IF( $F2 > ROWS( $A$1:$A$5 ) , $F1 , $F2 ) ) )
```

[image]